# Creating a List of forgein keys in django model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm trying to make 2 models in Django that are interconnected one called pathways and one called courses. I wrote a Json file, that I was hoping to use load data on, where the tables are set up like this

courses:

```
    "code": 1964, #primary key
    "name": "Documentary in the 21st Century",
    "category": "IHSS",
```

and pathways:

```
    "id": 1, #primary key
    "name": "Arts",
    "inquiries": [
        1080,
        1300,
        1170,
        1700
    ]
```

As you can see I want the model pathways to contain a list of foreign keys pointing to several different courses, but I'm new to Django and can't find anything helpful online.

Comment: You can't find much help, because you don't write models in json but in python. Have you gone through [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)?

Comment: yea  i have written the models out i just thought this would be the easiest way to display it

Answer (score 1):

Yopu should take a look at ManyToManyField configuration for the second model. It would be something like this:

```
inquiries = models.ManyToManyField(Courses)
```

But be aware that Django is assigning additional id field to all models, so you should use that instead of code in your first model, which can still have code filed if this is an information you need to preserve.